# TextFrame.Characters.Font.Name doesn't change the font of Chinese charatcers in excel shape

Tags: vba, excel

The title pretty much tells it all.

My code is like the below:

```
sh.TextFrame.Characters.Font.Name = "SimSun"
```

This code only changes the font for all English and single byte symbols.

All double byte symbols and the Chinese characters stay the default font.

I have tried TextFrame2 as well, same result.

I am on excel 2007.

Anyone who can help? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a Microsoft help desk article in Japanese explaining the issue.

Excel divides the font name of 1 byte english characters and two byte chinese / japanese characters as different modules in vba.

Solution is as follows.

```
sh.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.NameFarEast = "SimSun"
sh.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Font.Name = "SimSun"
```

The first line changes the font of all 2 byte characters in the shape text box and the second line changes the font for all single byte letters.

Far East... wow